# error de carácter pillow python

Tags: python

como podria corregir este error para que pueda permitir caracteres raros tambien que se vean los emojis
gracias!

aquí dejo mi codigo:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont


font_size=36
width=500
height=100
back_ground_color=(255,255,255)
font_size=36
font_color=(0,0,0)


unicode_text = u""

im  =  Image.new ( "RGB", (width,height), back_ground_color )
draw  =  ImageDraw.Draw ( im )
unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype("Montserrat-Thin.ttf", font_size,encoding='utf-8')
draw.text ( (10,10), unicode_text, font=unicode_font, fill=font_color )

im.save("text.jpg")
```

imagen del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La fuente que estás utilizando no incorpora los caracteres que estás pidiendo y los sustituye por el fallback.

Si sustituyes esa tipografía por una que los incorpore (como por ejemplo [STIX](https://www.stixfonts.org/)) funciona correctamente:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

width = 500
height = 100
back_ground_color = (255, 255, 255)
font_size = 36
font_color = (0, 0, 0)

unicode_text = ''

im = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), back_ground_color)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
unicode_font = ImageFont.FreeTypeFont('stixgeneral-regular.otf', font_size, encoding='utf-8')
draw.text((10, 10), unicode_text, font=unicode_font, fill=font_color)

im.save('text.jpg')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, y para hacerlo con otra fuente como lo podria hacer?, o que se deberia de hacer para que funcione como esa fuente STIX

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta... Si quieres escribir un carácter en una tipografía específica, esa tipografía debe incorporar ese carácter. Si no lo incorpora jamás podrá representarlo.

Comment: Solo queria donde encontrar esas fuentes que permita esos caracteres